# Xpath expression returns empty output

Tags: xpath, xidel

My xidel command is the following:

```
xidel "https://www.iec-iab.be/nl/contactgegevens/c360afae-29a4-dd11-96ed-005056bd424d" -e '//div[@class="consulentdetail"]'
```

This should extract all data in the divs with class `consulentdetail`
Nothing special I thought but it wont print anything.

Can anyone help me finding my mistake?

//EDIT: When I use the same expression in Firefox it finds the desired tags

Comment: What does `//div` find? If that finds nothing, it's not a problem with the XPath expression.

Comment: It does indeed find nothing. But `join(//div, "")` outputs a bunch of text

Comment: Curious, for some reason I do get results for `//*[@class="consulentdetail"]`

Comment: @Tomalak yes i noticed this too. But on the other hand `/*[@class="consulentdetail"]/span` is not working while again `/*[@class="consulentdetail"]//span` is...

Comment: I don't have an explanation for this. On first glance, it does not make any sense.

Comment: @Fuzzyma have you been able to decode the email from this site? if so, please share solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site you are connecting to obviously checks the user agent string and delivers different pages, according to the user agent string it gets sent.

If you instruct `xidel` to send a user agent string, impersonating as e.g. Firefox on Windows 10, your query starts to work:

```
> ./xidel --silent  --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0" "http://www.iec-iab.be/nl/contactgegevens/c360afae-29a4-dd11-96ed-005056bd424d" -e '//div[@class="consulentdetail"]'
Lidnummer11484 2 N 73
TitelAccountant, Belastingconsulent
TaalNederlands
Accountant sinds4/04/2005
Belastingconsulent sinds4/04/2005
AdresStationsstraat 2419550 HERZELE
Telefoon+32 (53) 41.97.02
Fax+32 (53) 41.97.03
AdresStationsstraat 2419550 HERZELE
Telefoon+32 (53) 41.97.02
Fax+32 (53) 41.97.03
GSM+32 (474) 29.00.67
Websitehttp://abbeloosschinkels.be
E-mail

<!--
document.write("<a href=mailto:");document.write(decrypt(unescCtrlCh("5yÃ¿Ã^Ã (pÃ±_!13!Â­[Ã®Ã¸Ã»!13!5Ã£Ã©vÂ¦ÃÃ§j|°W"),"Iate1milrve%ster"));document.write(">");document.write(decrypt(unescCtrlCh("5yÃ¿Ã^Ã (pÃ±_!13!Â­[Ã®Ã¸Ã»!13!5Ã£Ã©vÂ¦ÃÃ§j|°W"),"Iate1milrve%ster"));document.write("</a>");
-->
```

As a rule of thumb, when doing Web scraping and getting weird results:

1. Check the page in a browser with Javascript disabled.
2. Send a user agent string simulating a Web browser.